# Selecting friends alerts

Tags: mysql, sql

```
I HAVE TABLE USER 

USERID    NAME
1        JOHN DEO
2        JANE DEO
3        FRED DEO


TABLE ALERTS

ID   USERID        MSG

1    USERID3       HELLO 1
2    USERID1       HELLO 2
3    USERID3       HELLO 3
4    USERID2       HELLO 4



TABLE FRIENDS

ID   USERID      FRIEND

1    USERID3     USERID2
```

so the question is my userid is USERID3 and USERID2 is my friend
so i want to select all my friends MSG in table alerts

here is my query

```
SELECT msg
  FROM alerts IN (SELECT 
                    FROM friends
                   WHERE userid = 'USERID3' OR friend = 'USERID2')
```

so i want to be getting msg from my friend and also my friend gets my msg

we share each other msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a `UNION ALL` within the subquery after `IN` operator :

```
SELECT msg
  FROM alerts
 WHERE userid IN (SELECT friend FROM friends WHERE friend = 'USERID2'
                   UNION ALL
                  SELECT userid FROM friends WHERE userid = 'USERID3')
```

Comment: using this line SELECT friend FROM friends WHERE friend = 'USERID2', if if i have alot friends and want to get there msg, because this seems to be selecting only 1 friend

Comment: but question is not as you commented here, seems you need to give more details @moblatom what's the exact criteria for friendship?

Comment: i gave example just if i select 1 friend, but assume if i  have multiple friends, can that query retrieve all MSG of my friends more than one

Comment: of course it can retrieve provided the proper criteria is stated. You can edit the question according to keeping this in mind @moblatom